# Three.js place a plane through perpendicular by line

Tags: three.js, line, plane

I have an a **line** and **plane** in 3D space. I want to place plane's width and length line as perpendicular by line. Please see my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sea421/nvgcx72d/33/).

I am newbie at both three.js and vector calculation.

1. Current 2. Desired result

### [image: Example]

Please advice me. (Apologies for my bad English)

JS code:

```js
let renderer;
let camera;
let controls;

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(54, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xfefefe));
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

camera.position.set(5, 2, 7.5);


controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);


let gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(4, 4);
scene.add(gridHelper);

//line is defined by p0-p1
var p0 = new THREE.Vector3(-2, 2, 1);
var p1 = new THREE.Vector3(2, -1, -1);

var material2 = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x0000ff
});

//draw the line for visual reference
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(p0, p1);
var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material2);
scene.add(line);

// Plane
var planeGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(3, 3, 3);
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: "pink",
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.5,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
}));

//done!

scene.add(plane);



let animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you want this??
[image]

just add this code to your fiddle before `scene.add(plane);`

```js
plane.position.x = (p1.x + p0.x) / 2;
plane.position.y = (p1.y + p0.y) / 2;
plane.position.z = (p1.z + p0.z) / 2 ;
plane.lookAt(p0);
```

Then whatever the vectors you create for `p0` and `p1`, the plane will always be perpendicular to them and positioned in the middle of the line length.

Here's the [fiddle I have created with the sample](https://jsfiddle.net/Gangula/9pha27sd/3/)

If this answer solves your question, please mark it as **answer accepted**, in that way will also help other users with the same question to know it was right.

Comment: One-liner: `plane.position.addVectors(p1, p2).multiplyScalar(0.5);` :)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is totally what I want :)

Comment: Glad it was helpful, you can apply the oneliner suggested by prisioner849 to replace the calculations befor .lookAt. As you said you were newbie with vectors, I preferred to show you the basic case.

Comment: When I try viewing the fiddle, it just displays a white screen that reads "Place plane so that it goes along given line, and control direction by third point." How do I fix the fiddle to work?