# How to find 3D coordinates of point perpendicular to line's mid point

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js

(I'm using Javascript/Typescript and Three.js)

I have **a straight line** between two vectors, say `{x:1, y:3, z:5}` and `{x:7, y:8, z:10}`.

On the **mid-point** of that line, imagine a disc (say having radius 1) that is oriented perpenticular to that line.

How can I get **a point** on the cirumfence of that imaginary disc?

I know there are infinite points, but I'm just looking to compute 1 (any) point on the disc's circumefence with a perpendicular connection to the line's mid point.

Comment: This seems like more of a [Math question](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65020488/three-js-place-a-plane-through-perpendicular-by-line/65021348?noredirect=1#comment114968419_65021348)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. A simple way that requires little math, and lets Three.js handle the heavy-lifting is to use an [Object3D](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D) nested inside another: the child object is the "ring", and the parent object moves the ring to the midpoint and "looks" down the line to make it perpendicular.

```js
// Create end vectors
var v1 = new THREE.Vector3(1, 3, 5);
var v2 = new THREE.Vector3(7, 8, 10);

// Get midpoint
var mid = new THREE.Vector3();
mid.addVectors(v1, v2);
mid.multiplyScalar(0.5);

// Nest child object inside parent
var parent = new THREE.Object3D();
var child = new THREE.Object3D();
parent.add(child);

// Set child position to any point in the XY plane with radius = 1
// This is a point in your "disc"
child.position.set(0, 1, 0);

// Move parent to midpoint
parent.position.copy(mid);

// Rotate parent to look towards end of the line
// This makes the "disc" perpendicular to the line
parent.lookAt(v1);

// Get world position of child 
var discPoint = new THREE.Vector3();
child.getWorldPosition(discPoint);
console.log(discPoint);
```

The local position of `child` is still `[0, 1, 0]`, but the world position, after translating and rotating the parent, is the answer you're looking for. Alternatively, you could simply use [Object3D.localToWorld](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.localToWorld), but I thought this parent/child example would illustrate the process more clearly.

Comment: lovely, thanks a lot for taking the time to break to the steps!